# AppEngine: Get current serving application version

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a simple way to get the current serving application version in AppEngine?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']`

Comment: This is not deprecated. Getting the current version this way is perfectly fine. The deprecated key is APPLICATION_ID and get_application_id() function should be used instead.

Comment: The result is something like `my-version.383096322806301043`, so split on the dot if you just want the version name. I guess the second part is a timestamp, judging by Marco's answer on this page.

Comment: To complement Pat's response I extract it from this line

major_ver, minor_ver = os.environ.get('CURRENT_VERSION_ID').rsplit('.',1);

Comment: `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` isn't documented, I think it should be `GAE_VERSION`, according to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#environment_variables

Comment: *Update*: looks like the difference between `GAE_VERSION` and `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` is that the former is just the version name, while the latter is `<version name>.<timestamp>` (as described in the other answers).

Answer (score 18):

```
String version = SystemProperty.version.get();
String applicationVersion = SystemProperty.applicationVersion.get();
```

This is the syntax:

```
public static final SystemProperty applicationVersion
```

The major version number for the currently running version of the application plus a timestamp at which it was deployed. Has the key, "com.google.appengine.application.version".

See [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty.html)

PS. One puzzle still remains. What does timestamp next to version means and how to read it??

EDIT: Here is the key to the mystery.

```
 Date UploadDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(
   applicationVersion.substring(applicationVersion.lastIndexOf(‌​".")+1))
   / (2 << 27) * 1000);
```

Comment: To convert the number at the end of the version into the deploy time as number of seconds since epoch, divide the value by 2^28. See:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5788 for a feature request for GAE around this. I just tested on a deployed version from this week (June, 2012), and that resulted in the correct timestamp.

Comment: So basically `Date UploadDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(applicationVersion.substring(applicationVersion.lastIndexOf(".")+1)) / (2 << 27) * 1000);`

Answer (score 10):

For Python (GAE SDK release: "1.4.2")

```
version_id = self.request.environ["CURRENT_VERSION_ID"].split('.')[1]

timestamp = long(version_id) / pow(2,28) 

version = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%d/%m/%y %X")
```

See http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/f86010e7cf3c71b4

Comment: `v << 28` is a little easier if you want to shift by 28 bits, and `2 ** 28` is a little easier if you want to do pow.

Comment: That will give you the version time.  Taking `[0]` instead of `[1]` in the first line will give you the version itself.

Answer (score 10):

```
from google.appengine.api import modules
modules.get_current_version_name()
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/functions

Answer (score 2):

For nodejs, I am not sure if this is documented.

process.env.GAE_VERSION

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the process' environment variables:

> GAE_VERSION

which is available when you deploy (gcloud app deploy) using the flag --version

Answer (score 1):

For those who want an update, environment variables set for a GAE instance as of September 2020:

GAE_VERSION is the one that seems to answer the original question.

Google doc:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables

The following environment variables are set by the runtime:

Environment variable    Description
GAE_APPLICATION The ID of your App Engine application. This ID is prefixed with 'region code~' such as 'e~' for applications deployed in Europe.

GAE_DEPLOYMENT_ID   The ID of the current deployment.

GAE_ENV The App Engine environment. Set to standard.

GAE_INSTANCE    The ID of the instance on which your service is currently running.

GAE_MEMORY_MB   The amount of memory available to the application process, in MB.

GAE_RUNTIME The runtime specified in your app.yaml file.

GAE_SERVICE The service name specified in your app.yaml file. If no service name is specified, it is set to default.

GAE_VERSION The current version label of your service.

GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT    The Cloud project ID associated with your application.

PORT    The port that receives HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experiments today, there are two `os.environ` variables that you can use to get the current app version:

1. `os.environ['GAE_VERSION']`: the version *name* only
2. `os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']`: a unique version identifier composed of *{version name}.{deployment id}*, which is equivalent to `os.environ['GAE_VERSION'] + '.' + os.environ['GAE_DEPLOYMENT_ID']`

It appears that the so-called "deployment id" can be right-shifted 28 bits to get a timestamp in epoch seconds (as other answers already described).

**For example**: I deployed version "101" of my app at *2021-03-04T00:17:12Z* and I'm seeing the following values:

- `os.environ['GAE_VERSION']`: `'101'`
- `os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']`: `'101.433474146608888597'`
- `os.environ['GAE_DEPLOYMENT_ID']`: `'433474146608888597'`

You can use the following code to get the version name and timestamp from `os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']`:

```
>>> import os
>>> import datetime
>>> version_id = os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']  # example: '101.433474146608888597'
>>> name, ts = version_id.split('.')
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(ts) >> 28))
>>> dt.isoformat()
'2021-03-04T00:17:12'
```

**Disclaimer**: Most of this functionality is undocumented and the deployment ID format may be [subject to change](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine-python/c/-GAQ5888cbQ/m/Kk4OSXY_gmEJ).