# How do I get the Application ID at runtime

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need the Application ID to construct the correct `<applicationid>.appspotmail.com` address, and I'm having a hard time finding out how to retrieve it at runtime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The recommended approach now is to use `app_identity.get_application_id()`:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/functions.html#get_application_id

See the warning box here for details:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Requests_and_Domains

Comment: Is there any way to get the current version name during runtime?

Comment: @Lipis, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948861/appengine-get-current-serving-application-version

Comment: The warning box seems to be long gone, but I found this in the [release notes](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) from July 2011: "The SDK application environment variable will now be prefixed with dev~. The new preferred way of retrieving your app id is to use appidentity.get_application_id(). The --default_partition flag can be used for applications whose code relied on a specific environment variable."

Comment: Is there a way to get time from that?

Comment: @MeLight The time of what?

Comment: @SaxonDruce the time of the deployment

Comment: @MeLight Some of the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948861/appengine-get-current-serving-application-version describe how to get the date out of the number in the version ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using:

```
os.environ['APPLICATION_ID']
```

Comment: This is now considered harmful, see warning box on http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Requests_and_Domains