# How do I decode GAE version_id?

Tags: google-app-engine

I notice that the version_id in a deployment is represented as a ISO timestamp in the admin log. Is it possible to decode the environment variable CURRENT_VERSION_ID to be a timestamp, as well? Some examples:

```
2013-02-01T02:44:34Z 364988112448279806 
2013-02-01T02:46:26Z 364988142569033474
2013-02-01T02:51:39Z 364988226566178837
```

Comment: This definitely looks like a timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259804/8418), which is actually not really relevant there, you can [right shift by 28 bits](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-python/-GAQ5888cbQ) the version id:

```
version_id = long(self.request.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID'].split('.')[1])
timestamp = version_id >> 28 # epochtime
```

Further you can format it in a more human readable form like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
version = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

So this magic number that @ShayErlichmen found out is the 2^28.

Comment: Thanks! The comment there also points out that long(version_id) >> 28 is a little more clear. I wonder what those 28 bits are used for...

Comment: Might also be nice to quote the original source: "While the format is internal and subject to change, at the moment you can right shift by 28 bits." http://goo.gl/dEqwM

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to divide the version in 268935300.571429 to get epoch time.
[I wrote a simple spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqK1I3zTjmMAdDBJal9GZk94TzBGelloSlVFZnB0TFE#gid=0) to reverse engineer the numbers but it needs more samples to get an accurate number.