# Get current deployed timestamp in AppEngine/Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Can I get the deployed timestamp of current application version in AppEngine/Go?

It seems helpful, but not sure how to implement in AppEngine/Go application code.

- [AppEngine: Get current serving application version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948861/appengine-get-current-serving-application-version)
- https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/v1beta2/reference/apps/modules/versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this link [AppEngine: Get current serving application version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948861/appengine-get-current-serving-application-version), the suggested answer is written in `python`

```
os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']
```

Above code is trying to retrieve the environment variable with name `CURRENT_VERSION_ID`, Equivalent code in `go` would be:

```
import (
    ...
    "os"
)
...
versionText := os.Getenv("CURRENT_VERSION_ID")
```

According to one of the comments, the result would be in this format `my-version.383096322806301043`, you should use `strings.Split` method to split it by `.`, eg:

```
import (
    ...
    "strings"
)
...
timestampString := strings.Split(versionText, ".")[1]
```

Comment: Thanks! https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled